# BIOS Update EXE - Lenovo E41-55

Tags: windows, laptop, bios

Lenovo E41-55 laptop support page lists BIOS update file (which is an EXE) only under Windows 10. The download is completely missing when I Select OS as Windows 11 therein.

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-e-series-laptops/e41-55/downloads/driver-list

Is it necessary that I must have Windows 10 to run the BIOS update EXE? Will it be equally safe to run it under Windows 11?

My hypothesis is -

BIOS Update may reboot system several times before finishing when you run an EXE file that updates BIOS. If BIOS update is going to reset BIOS, it might disable secure boot, TPM etc and Windows 11 may be unbootable leaving the process unfinished?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to run the BIOS update from the download. Download the BIOS EXE file and run it from start menu.

It should not matter whether you are running Windows 11 or 10.

Make sure all your apps are closed as the BIOS Update will prepare, then restart and do the update separately from the OS.

Re your hypothesis:   I have not seen my Lenovo BIOS updates do several restarts - normally just one.  Nor have I seen settings go bad from a BIOS update.

I have updated BIOS on my Windows 10 machines when I had Windows 10 and on my Windows 11 machines now.

Comment: Thanks @John for the answer. +1 from me. I wonder why Lenovo has not listed BIOS update EXE under Windows 11. This is true for several models seems where the Laptop supports Windows 11. Do you have anything to comment on that? Or whatever Laptops you updated BIOS with on Windows 11, was is there on the Support page under Windows 11? Thanks.

Comment: Since BIOS updates without the OS running, it should work just fine for you.. On my older machine (running Windows 11 insider) the support page is Windows 10. On my newer machine that came with Windows 11, the support page is for Windows 11.

Comment: My E41-55 comes with Windows 11 pre-installed but Lenovo support page lists most items only for Windows 10 for this model!

Comment: The BIOS update should work .

Comment: Anyway with BIOS update I did not take any chance.  I wiped Windows 11 and installed Windows 10 first. BIOS update happened smoothly after running that EXE from Windows 10. I also made sure to disconnect Internet before running EXE  & made sure that there are no pending updates, just in case unexpected updates undesirably reboot the system. I may continue to use Windows 10 for a while before really moving to Windows 11.